# How can I config/use MapCache/MapServer to serve my MBtiles as WMS service?

Tags: geoserver, wms, mapserver, mbtiles, mapcache

Currently I am using GeoServer for my Map Service as WMS.

I use TileMill for creating a customised map with styling and SHP files and then export as mbtiles.

I have tried TileServer-PHP & TileStream as temporary solution for z/x/y.

I wonder how I am able to setup a MapServer to consume MBtiles and serve out as WMS standard.

Please assist me on this as I am still quite new to GIS and have to use OpenSource technology.

**Update**

I use MapProxy to serve out the basemap into WMS OGC Standards